# SML function to remove elements in a list

Tags: list, sml

Can someone help me write a function to drop elements in a list:

```
drop 3 [1,2,3,4,5] ==> [4,5]
```

so this one drops first three elements.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built in function `List.drop`, or, if you want to write it yourself, for some reason, do something like this:

```
fun drop 0 L = L
  | drop n [] = raise Range
  | drop n (x::xs) = drop (n - 1) xs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.76 [built: Sun Jul 14 09:59:19 2013]
- List.drop ([1,2,3,4], 2);
val it = [3,4] : int list
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation?

Comment: The `List.drop` function is used as follows: `List.drop (L, n)` evaluates to the list that results from dropping the first `n` elements from `L`. It's an SML standard library function.